# Conditional types can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Say I want to write a utility type like `Merge`

```
type Merge<A, B> = {
  [P in (keyof A | keyof B)]: P extends keyof A ? A[P] : B[P]  
}
```

However, the above code would get

> Type 'P' cannot be used to index type 'B'.

Though I can write it like

```
type Merge<A, B> = {
  [P in (keyof A | keyof B)]: P extends keyof A ? A[P] : P extends keyof B ? B[P] : never
}
```

But isn't it too verbose?

I have limited the type of `P` in the `P in (keyof A | keyof B)`, so why does the `P extends keyof B` still needed?